# Change after i click that button

Tags: php, mysql

Help me please to make this code works perfectly

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['btn-verif'])){ 
      $q1 = "UPDATE `user2` SET `activecode` = `1` WHERE `user2`.`email` = '$baseACC';";
      $result = mysql_query($q1);
      if(mysql_query($q1)==TRUE){
              echo "UPDATE SUCCES";
        }else {
            echo "UPDATE FAIL";
        }
        }echo "Wrong Code";
        ?>
```

I want if i press button(`btn-verif`) that SQL query execute and update the `activecode` into  `1` from `0` based on `email = '$baseACC';` and if that code works like what i want (`TRUE`) he will be execute this code `echo "UPDATE SUCCES";`

this my html code

```
<p>Dear <?php echo $userRowX['namalengkap']; ?></p> 
<p>You need to <strong>verified</strong> your account by click this link</p> 
<a href="verified.php" target="_blank"><button class="btn btn-primary" name="btn-verif">Verify Your Account Now</button></a>
```

> Sorry for my bad english ;)

Comment: where is your  html form??

Comment: @user1234 `<p>Dear <?php echo $userRowX['namalengkap']; ?></p>
<p>You need to <strong>verified</strong> your account by click this link</p>
<a href="verified.php" target="_blank"><button class="btn btn-primary" name="btn-verif">Verify Your Account Now</button></a>`

Comment: there is no form. you have to pass it as a get variable.

Comment: i just want make a button to change that rows `activecode` not a input form

Comment: hey this php code and html both are in verified.php?

Comment: @coder maybe you mean i must make this code
`<form>
<a href="verified.php" target="_blank"><button class="btn btn-primary" name="btn-verif">Verify Your Account Now</button>
</form>
`

Comment: @user1234 that just confirm the user has activate/confirm his account, want to see the code?

Comment: @arigohafnan, i have posted my ans pls check

Answer (score 1):

use `form tag` in your form with `post method`

```
<p>Dear <?php echo $userRowX['namalengkap']; ?></p> <p>You need to <strong>verified</strong> your account by click this link</p> 

<form method= "Post">
<a href="verified.php" target="_blank"><button class="btn btn-primary" name="btn-verif">Verify Your Account Now</button></a>
</form>
```

Comment: that doest'n work,  thanks for trying to helping me :)

Answer (score 0):

This is just a way to do it. But i would suggest the ans by @user1234

```
  <?php
  if(isset($_GET['verify'])){ 
  $q1 = "UPDATE `user2` SET `activecode` = `1` WHERE `user2`.`email` = '$baseACC';";
  $result = mysql_query($q1);
  if(mysql_query($q1)==TRUE){
          echo "UPDATE SUCCES";
    }else {
        echo "UPDATE FAIL";
    }
    }
    else{
     echo "Wrong Code";
    }
    ?>
   <p>Dear <?php echo $userRowX['namalengkap']; ?></p>
   <p>You need to <strong>verified</strong> your account by click this link</p>
   <a href="verified.php?verify=1" target="_blank"><button class="btn btn-primary" name="btn-verif">Verify Your Account Now</button></a>
```

Comment: echo "Wrong Code"; shoud be inside }

Comment: that doest'n work, thanks for trying to helping me :)

Comment: i tired to find the solutions